# Редирект на обратную страницу, после авторизации вконтакте

Tags: php, javascript

После авторизации вконтакте, по инструкциям, указанным [здесь](http://vk.com/dev/Auth)
мне необходимо попасть на страницу, с которой была запрошена авторизация .

```
пользователь будет переадресован на указанный в параметре authUrl адрес с полями: uid, first_name, last_name, photo, photo_rec, hash
```

Можно ли как-нибудь также передать адрес текущей страницы, чтобы я там смог сделать

```
header("Location: /адрес.php");
```

Поднимаю вопрос.

Comment: location.href ? причем тут php то ? это js.

Comment: как передавать я знаю.Вопрос, как присобачить ко всему тому пуллу этот адрес?

Comment: Так что-ли ?

    <!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?105"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      VK.init({apiId: 3154115});
    </script>
    
    <!-- Put this div tag to the place, where Auth block will be -->
    <div id="vk_auth"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Auth("vk_auth", {width: "200px", authUrl: location.href});
    </script>

Comment: А почему-бы не во всплывающем окне не авторизовываться? Авторизацию прошел - окно закрыл. Или я не понял вопроса?

Comment: Если я сделаю 

     authUrl: location.href}

, то получается у меня закроется всплывающее окно с подсказкой, ведь страница перезагрузится.

Необходимо, чтобы на сервере авторизовался, без перезагрузки передал параметры. 

     $('#auth_user').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   url: "http://site.ru/vklogin.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: $('#vk_auth').serialize(),

   success: function(response) {
    
  //обработка успешной отправки
    }

Но, страница загружается быстрее чем ее останавливает скрипт.

Comment: в обработчике submit return false; в конце лишним не будет. Точно не помню причин, но preventDefault() работает не всегда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
header("Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']");
```